# In mongoose, how do I remove only one document found in a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose we can do this:

```
User.findOne({age: 30}, callback);
```

But we can NOT do this:

```
User.removeOne({age: 30}, callback); // ERR: has no method removeOne
```

So how we can implement removeOne method in mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the Mongoose method you are looking for is [`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove).

So usage would be:

```
User.findOneAndRemove({age: 30}, callback);
```